# How to get results from Concurrent::Promise::all?

Tags: ruby

Using [conccurrent-ruby](https://github.com/ruby-concurrency/concurrent-ruby), how can I execute a set of promises and then get the results?

Here is an example of what I *would like* to be able to do (The test passes because it never reaches the 'then' block.

```
it "can aggregate the results" do
  Concurrent::Promise::all?(
    Concurrent::Promise.execute { 42 },
    Concurrent::Promise.execute { 43 },
  ).then do |result|
      binding.pry
      expect(result).to eq([42, 43])
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to execute the the `.all?` promises you need to call `.execute` and `.wait`, that means it will execute then wait until the result is ready, **note `wait` is blocking meaning it will block your code`.**
ex:

```rb
Concurrent::Promise.all?(
  Concurrent::Promise.new { 42 },
  Concurrent::Promise.new { 43 }
).then do |result|
  puts 'finished promises'
end.execute.wait
```

However if you wish to get the results after the promises are finished you can use `.zip` method, ex:

```rb
Concurrent::Promise.zip(
  Concurrent::Promise.execute { 42 },
  Concurrent::Promise.execute { 43 }
).then do |result|
  expect(result).to eq([42, 43])
end.wait
```

**Note: There are some differences between `.zip` and `.all?` check the docs: https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/concurrent-ruby/Concurrent/Promise**